# Is it possible to connect the Google TV remote with an Android tv-box like Minix?

Tags: google-tv, android-tv

I have found the Google TV remote source code. Would it be possible to modify the code so the Google TV remote could work on my [MiniX](http://www.minix.us/) box? It should be possible since their both are on a android platform? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly subjective in the context of hardware/software hacking.

MiniX indeed uses the Android platform (judging by their website), however, it is a dedicated set top-box and maybe the protocol for talking to the remote is different to one of Google TV kind.

Have the crowd behind it, shared some source code or protocol specifications?

Might be worth checking around on forums to see if anyone has hacked the top-box that can do so.

Its a gamble having said that but it does sound fun trying to get the Google TV remote to work with it :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have searching for the protocols and I could not find any specifications on it, I know that the Google Tv remote uses a protocol called Anymote

https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/

But I think that it only works on a Google TV :-(